# Override JAXRS @QueryParameter value using Post-matched Request Filter

Tags: java, filter, jax-rs, query-string

I have a method wherein I need to override the values of the query parameter based on certain computations:

```
@GET
@Path("/channel")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@OptimizedDate
public FancountAndChannel computeFanCount(
        @QueryParam("artist") String artistId,
        @OptimizableDate @QueryParam("date") Integer date, //override this using filters
        @QueryParam("channel") String channel) {

    //do stuffs here
}
```

My filter looks like this:

```
@OptimizedDate
public class OptimizedDateFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
    if (//certain condition) {
        //im hoping this method would change the "date" value
        Integer optimizedDate = //compute date here
        updateDateParameter(context, "date", optimizedDate );
    }
}   

private void updateDateParameter(ContainerRequestContext context, String fieldName, Integer optimizedDate) {

    //TODO: wont work, only for post-matching filters
    URI oldUri = context.getUriInfo().getRequestUri();
    URI newUri = null;
    try {
        newUri = new URIBuilder(oldUri).setParameter(fieldName, String.valueOf(optimizedDate)).build();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOGGER.debug("oldUri={}\nnewUri={}", oldUri, newUri);
    context.setRequestUri(newUri);

    //TODO: wont work: query parameters are immutable
    //context.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters().putSingle(fieldName, String.valueOf(optimizedDate));
    //context.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters().add(fieldName, Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(optimizedDate)));
}
```

I want to override the value, or set it (when its null). However, most of the methods I have tried are using immutable objects.

Is there any better way of doing this using filters? I may have to apply the same logic across a lot of methods, copy-pasting is not my style.

**Summary of Requirements:**

1. Value is to be computed and decided at runtime
2. Logic is to be applied across a variety of JAXRS endpoints ONLY

Comment: You can write a request wrapper and modify your parameters.

Comment: @RomanC can you expound on that? just curious, im open to any ideas. including not using filters/interceptors. something that works cleanly

Comment: So you don't know how to write request wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

if you want only to set a value when its null than use  @DefaultValue("default value you want")

```
  public FancountAndChannel computeFanCount(
            @QueryParam("artist") String artistId,
            @OptimizableDate @DefaultValue("default value you want")   @QueryParam("date") Integer date, //override this using filters
            @QueryParam("channel") String channel) {

}
```

Comment: That won't work. The value is computed and decided at runtime

Comment: In you question you said this "I want to override the value, or set it (when its null)"  so use a default value. if request contains the default value do your processing or if its contain a value then override it.no need of filter if you only want this in only one REST method

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found is

```
public class DelegationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {

    final Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
    parameterMap.put(fieldName, new String[] { String.valueOf(optimizedDate) });
    
   }
}
```

This worked in liberty server. I hope it would work for you too.

**Please note that this one updates the parametermap and not parameters. I dint find a way to update the parameters**